# Laravel 5.1: How AuthController runs methods not implemented in its file?

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, controller, routes, laravel-5.1

I've implemented the [Basic Authentication described on the Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication).

Part of the process is setting up Routes for Authentication on the routes.php file:

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

But, going through the AuthController inside the Auth directory, I cannot find those methods (getLogin, postLogin, etc.).

**How does this work if the methods aren't there?**

or

**Where are those methods?**

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments at the top of the AuthController..

> By default, this controller uses a simple trait to add these
>   behaviors.

... the 'AuthenticatesUsers' trait is where the methods listed in the question are called. You can find it at 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers'.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't even know what traits are, now I'm looking into it.